# Code sample for Paypal subscription with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, paypal

Is there a code sample or a really good article that talks about integrating Paypal subscriptions with a ASP.NET website?

I'd like to provide a 30 day trial period during which they are not charged (even if they cancel). If they choose to continue, they are charged every month. The paypal documentation is not very helpful and I've yet to come across a code sample that implements this.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hi, take a look at http://www.codersbarn.com/post/2008/07/10/ASPNET-PayPal-Subscriptions-IPN.aspx - see if that helps?

Comment: Hi - I had seen this article earlier. This doesn't talk about a monthly subscription service.

Answer (score 0):

Disclosure: this is a blog posting I put out:

http://www.codersbarn.com/post/2008/07/10/ASPNET-PayPal-Subscriptions-IPN.aspx

From memory, if you check the PayPal parameters, there is a way to set up trial period.